# How to Visual Basic recognize small lattin leter "č"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with Visual basic in Excel and I have a cell with the value "Gotovinski račun".
Another cell should be an English version of that value.

My code is:

`If Range("A2").Value = "Gotovinski račun" Then Range("D2").Value = "Cash account"`

Problem is that VBA can't recognize the small Lattin letter "č".

Any ideas?

Comment: One option is to use the char code `= "Gotovinski ra" & ChrW$(&H10D) & "un" then `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that the VBA Editor only supports ANSI characters. You could try setting your *"language for programs that do not support unicode"* setting to Croation (or whichever language) (*in administrative language settings*).

Note that with that setting, the test string is properly displayed in the VBE:

[image]

If that is not an option, then you need to insert any characters with a code `> 255` using the `Chrw$` function.  See the comment by @AlexK for an example.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround consists in using a `Like` comparison with one (ore more) `?` wildcards replacing the *c plus caron* character `č`:

```
With Sheet1.Range("A2")
    If .Value Like "Gotovinski ra?un" Then
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = "Cash account"
    Else
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = "'" & .Value & "' not found"
    End If
End With
```